# What's the difference between an 'accessory' and 'editing accessory' in a table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

You have the same options in both and the icons seem to go to the same part of the table view cell (right hand side), so do they actually have any difference?

Comment: You can answer your question by viewing the documentation for the `accessoryType` and `editingAccessoryType` properties of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, but I find the Apple documentation extremely poor

Comment: It's reference documentation. It is meant to give you basic details. For these two properties the descriptions answer your question. Don't ignore the documentation when you need basic reference information.

Answer (score 0):

The accessory shows when the table view is in **normal state**, while the editing accessory displays when the table view is in **editing mode**.

You can switch between the two states by changing `UITableView`'s `isEditing` property or by tapping on `UIViewController`'s `editButtonItem`.